# What does `yy` in vim do with `set clipboard=unnamedplus`?

Tags: vim

I'm running vim 7.4 on OSX. In my `.vimrc` file I have the single line:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

and in this case I'm trying to figure out where the line I yank with `yy` is going. I've tried some obvious registers, e.g. `"xp`, `"*p`, but they don't contain the yanked line.

I even tried pasting using Command-V after yanking, and it doesn't insert the yanked line so the `yy` doesn't seem to be affecting the system clipboard.

Comment: `:h unnamedplus` says it goes to the `+` register.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug, but `"+p` doesn't do it for me either.

Comment: What's the output of `:echo has('clipboard')`?

Comment: It displays `1`

Comment: I found the `:reg` command which displays all the registers. Apparently it is yanking text to the `"` (double quote) and `0` registers - both are getting a copy of the yanked text.

Comment: And with `set clipboard=...,autoselect` it will also yank to the `*` register and then `p` will paste the yanked text.

Answer (score 1):

see `:h clipboard-unnamedplus` for further details.

This option only works in vim-Versions compiled with the `+X11`-feature!
(you can see that under `:version` e.g.)

That means: you can only use this register the mentioned way, if your vim can handle the "X11-yank-register". Is that the case, so you can use this register for all your yank-and-past-operations.